# How to check if there is value or not using MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Well here is the script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("**8", $con);
$sql = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE headset");
$qry= "INSERT INTO `headset` (`WebTitle`) VALUES ('". $_POST[webtitle] ."')";
$sql = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE headset2");
$qry= "INSERT INTO `headset2` (`WebSlogan`) VALUES ('". $_POST[webslogan] ."')";


if (!mysql_query($qry,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
header("location: ../generalsettings.php");
exit();

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is just for the one value:
I have a form with 2 boxes and I want to achieve the following: if only one of the boxes is filled I would like to truncate and insert only the value that is filled, and do nothing with the other unfilled box.
I hope you got my point.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the mysql_query functions!!! Better use the pdo class

http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

if (isset($_POST['webtitle']) && $_POST['webtitle'] != '') {
   try {
      $db->query('TRUNCATE TABLE headset');
      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO headset (WebTitle) VALUES (?)");
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST[webtitle]);
      $stmt->execute();
   } catch(PDOException $ex) {
      echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['webtitle']) && $_POST['webtitle'] != '') {
    // $_POST['webtitle'] code here
}
if (isset($_POST['webslogan']) && $_POST['webslogan'] != '') {
    // $_POST['webslogan'] code here
}
```

And the same for the other one

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I caught that immediately from the copy/paste and edited it out straight away. I would certainly appreciate it if you'd remove your downvote.

Comment: So the downvote stays because my valid code isn't written in precisely the way you want it to be?

Comment: It's not valid. MySQLi requires that you pass the "link" as the first argument to `_query()`. However the *real* problem is that you pass a user input value from `$_POST`, unescaped, directly into a query.

Comment: Just because you replaced `mysql_query()` with `mysqli_query()` did not make you code less of a crap.

Comment: @Dimono,Dave,Neal how about giving up the "deprecated function circlejerk" and actually answering the guy's question in the same format that it was asked?

Comment: Since his actual question was how to determing if it was submitted, I'll just go ahead and remove everything except that part

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for removing the downvote :) Sour that there's no way I'll get the selected answer though; c4pone's is much more complete than mine.

Comment: @Sammitch answering a question about code with serious security problems, without addressing said security problems in the answer, is not productive for anyone involved. Better to spend the time writing a clear answer that addresses all the issues and potential pitfalls than a quickfire answer than only addresses the exact question, that simply perpetuates the XY problem and guarantees that the OP will be back soon asking a question about why their security is compromised. Regarding "deprecated function circlejerk"s, it benefits everyone to spread the message that ext/mysql shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank, you. It work, BUT if I type both 2 values, it is inserting only the second one. The script cannot insert the 2 values in the same time. :)

Comment: Well no, of course not; you run the first IF statement for $_POST['webtitle'] and put all of its code in there, and then you run a second IF statement for $_POST['webslogan'] and put all of its code in there. I'll update my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Well, this is the code: `if (isset($_POST['webtitle']) && $_POST['webtitle'] != '') {
    $sql = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE headset");
    $qry= "INSERT INTO `headset` (`WebTitle`) VALUES ('". $_POST[webtitle] ."')";
}
if (isset($_POST['webslogan']) && $_POST['webslogan'] != '') {
    $sql = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE headset2");
    $qry= "INSERT INTO `headset2` (`WebSlogan`) VALUES ('". $_POST[webslogan] ."')";
}` And as I see it is the same, and it is not working. Tank you for the assistance, I really wanna make this :)

Comment: You need to execute each query inside the if statement; all you're doing right now is storing the querystring into a variable, you need to actually do something with it inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

to check if there is value in database do this

```
    $myquery= mysql_query(" select * from headset ");
   if(mysql_fetch_row($myquery)==0){ --//there is no data in your database
                                   }
    else {  --//there is data do what you like 
         }
```

- *please use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql